# Intercept Variable Type validation in Routes file

Tags: java, model-view-controller, playframework

I've started working on Play almost a week ago, what I'm trying to do right now is to intercept type validation done by routes file.
I'm doing fully server programming, no forms are involved all the data I get is through uri.Now consider following Rout

```
    GET /send/request/*to/*from     controllers.Req_controller.sendRequest(to: Int, from:Int)
```

if I'll enter a non numeric character or a string instead of an integer, It'll give me type violation error.
I don't want play to do this, i want to handle these errors myself, returning a JSon object is a good option.

But I don't want,

```
  Bad request  For request 'GET /send/request/3/f' [Cannot parse parameter from as Int: For input string: "f"]
```

Help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Params in `routes` with asterisk are for `String` spanning several 'slash-segments' and should be placed somwhere at the end of `routes` file, ie:

```
GET     /some/*path    controllers.Application.resolvePath(path: String)
```

will match:

```
http://domain.tld/some/a       it will pass 'a' String as a path param
http://domain.tld/some/a/b     it will pass 'a/b'
http://domain.tld/some/a/b/c   it will pass 'a/b/c'
```

In your case you should use 'colon version' of the param:

```
GET  /send/request/:to/:from  controllers.Req_controller.sendRequest(to: Integer, from:Integer)
```

*edit*

To make basic interception you can just override `onBadRequest()` method with [Global object](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaGlobal) (bottom).

You can also send whole `*path` as a `a/b/c` string to your controller (like in very first sample route in this answer) and then split it and validate part by part in some more sophisticated scenario, anyway as can you see there are ome possibilities and I'm sure that you'll choose something.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but whta I was trying to ask is "How can I intercept type validation at routes level" i.e how can I intercept a call or a request before it goes to Routes file for validation.